# sklearn Classification metrics

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, классификация, метрики

В пакете `sklearn` есть множество метрик позволяющих оценить качество классификации.

Бывает ли необходимость под конкретную задачу использовать конкретную метрику, которой нет в пакете?

Учитывается ли данная ситуация в самом пакете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос сформулирован так, что на него сложно дать однозначный ответ.

С одной стороны библиотека SciKit-Learn предлагает [очень много различных метрик для задач классификации](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#classification-metrics), а с другой стороны всегда может возникнуть необходимость использовать свою метрику - наиболее полезную для данной конкретной задачи.

В этом случае можно воспользоваться [sklearn.metrics.make_scorer()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html#sklearn.metrics.make_scorer):

```
>>> from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, make_scorer
>>> ftwo_scorer = make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=2)
>>> ftwo_scorer
make_scorer(fbeta_score, beta=2)
>>> from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> grid = GridSearchCV(LinearSVC(), param_grid={'C': [1, 10]},
...                     scoring=ftwo_scorer)
```

[Другой пример использования из англоязычной версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32401493/how-to-create-customize-your-own-scorer-function-in-scikit-learn)